# sql insert not in order

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am inserting few rows in my table, i don't know why the inserted rows are not in the order of insertion-

here is the java code -

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ". Value: " + entry.getValue());
    insert(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); //method to insert a single record
}
```

insert query :

```
insert into heightList(heightId,height) values(?,?)
```

the `sysout` log is : (printing all keys in order)

```
Key: 1. Value: some text
Key: 2. Value: some text
Key: 3. Value: some text
Key: 4. Value: some text
Key: 5. Value: some text
Key: 6. Value: some text
Key: 7. Value: some text
Key: 8. Value: some text
Key: 9. Value: some text
Key: 10. Value: some text
Key: 11. Value: some text
Key: 12. Value: some text
Key: 13. Value: some text
Key: 14. Value: some text
Key: 15. Value: some text
Key: 16. Value: some text
Key: 17. Value: some text
Key: 18. Value: some text
Key: 19. Value: some text
Key: 20. Value: some text
Key: 21. Value: some text
Key: 22. Value: some text
Key: 23. Value: some text
Key: 24. Value: some text
Key: 25. Value: some text
Key: 26. Value: some text
Key: 27. Value: some text
Key: 28. Value: some text
Key: 29. Value: some text
Key: 30. Value: some text
Key: 31. Value: some text
Key: 32. Value: some text
Key: 33. Value: some text
Key: 34. Value: some text
Key: 35. Value: some text
Key: 36. Value: some text
Key: 37. Value: some text
```

but this is what my table looks like after insertion -

```
heightId    height
1       some text
10      some text
11      some text
12      some text
13      some text
14      some text
15      some text
16      some text
17      some text
18      some text
19      some text
2       some text
20      some text
21      some text
22      some text
23      some text
24      some text
25      some text
26      some text
27      some text
28      some text
29      some text
3       some text
30      some text
31      some text
32      some text
33      some text
34      some text
35      some text
36      some text
37      some text
4       some text
5       some text
6       some text
7       some text
8       some text
9       some text
```

Why the rows are not in order, and how can i insert them in order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are being inserted in order. But it would appear you're inserting id numbers (ints) into a text-based field (char/varchar). Text sorting rules to **NOT** work with numbers.

if they are going into an int field, then look at whatever's doing the actual sorting.

Comment: so convert it to an int, then `order by id` will work properly. As it stands now it **IS** sorted properly, but only because you're lying to the database about what's in the field. it is NOT the db's job to try and GUESS what's in the field. You've told it it's text, so it's applying text-based rules.

Comment: i just altered the field to int, and the data is now in order, i really wasn't aware of this thing - thanks!